# fatal Error Unexpectedly while unwrapping an optional value while loading Comments

Tags: ios, json, swift

Hi guys i have been stuck in this problem for nearly 2 week

The Problem is that i am getting the error fatal Error Unexpectedly while unwrapping an optional value while i am loading comments..

I am trying to load JSON data For the Comments
in PopularShotsCollectionViewController

```
    import UIKit
    import FMMosaicLayout

    private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

    class PopularShotsCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
        private var shots : [Shot] = [Shot](){
            didSet{
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
        }


        var API_URL = Config.SHOT_URL
        var shotPages = 1


        var shot : Shot!
        var comments : [Comment] = [Comment]()
        var tableView : UITableView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


            let layout : FMMosaicLayout = FMMosaicLayout()
            self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = layout

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            self.title = "Popular"
            self.API_URL = Config.POPULAR_URL
            self.loadShots()
            self.loadComments()

       }

        func loadComments(){
 //  When i debug shot.commentsUrl does not return nil
         DribbleObjectHandler.getComments(shot.commentsUrl) { (comments) -> Void in
            self.comments = comments
          }
        }
```

But i am getting this error:
[image: The Log which shows the error]

The code for the getCommentsMethod

```
  class func getComments(commentsUrl : String, completion:(([Comment]) -> Void)) {
    var comments = [Comment]()
    let url = commentsUrl + "&access_token=" + Config.ACCESS_TOKEN

     HttpService.getJSON(url) { (jsonData) -> Void in

        for commentData in jsonData {
          let comment = Comment(data: commentData as! NSDictionary)
          comments.append(comment)
        }
         let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0), { () -> Void in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                completion(comments)
            })
         })
        }
    }
```

Code for the HttpService

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class HttpService {
    class func getJSON(url: String, callback:((NSArray) -> Void)) {
        let nsURL = NSURL(string: url)!
        Alamofire.request(.GET, nsURL).response { (request, response, data, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil{
                print("error")
            }

            if data != nil {
                let jsonData = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSArray
                print(jsonData)
                callback(jsonData)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you need more Code to solve the problem i am more than happy

And in PopularShotsCollectionViewController i have been loading shots also
with the same method

```
 func loadShots(){

      DribbleObjectHandler.getShots(API_URL) { (shots) -> Void in
        self.shots = shots
     }
}
```

but i get no error and it works perfectly
and code for the get Shots is same.. Just we access The Shot class in loadShots and we access The Comment Class in loadComments

The Comment Class

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Comment {

    var id : Int!
    var body : String!
    var date : String!

    var user : User!

    init(data : NSDictionary){

        self.id = data["id"] as! Int
        let bodyHTML = Utils.getStringFromJSON(data, key: "body")
        self.body = Utils.stripHTML(bodyHTML)

        let dateInfo = Utils.getStringFromJSON(data, key: "created_at")
        self.date = Utils.formatDate(dateInfo)

        if let userData = data["user"] as? NSDictionary {
            self.user = User(data: userData)
        }
    }
}
```

Code for the Shot Class

```
import Foundation

    class Shot: DribbbleBase {

        var imageUrl : String!
        var htmlUrl : String!
        var commentsUrl : String!
        var bucketsUrl : String!
        var likesUrl : String!
        var attachmentUrl : String!
        var reboundUrl : String!

        var title : String!
        var date : String!
        var description : String!
        var commentCount : Int!
        var viewsCount : Int!
        var likesCount : Int!
        var bucketsCount : Int!
        var attachmentsCount : Int!
        var reboundCount : Int!

        var user : User! 

       override init(data: NSDictionary) {
            super.init(data: data)

           self.commentCount = data["comments_count"] as! Int
            self.likesCount = data["likes_count"] as! Int
            self.viewsCount = data["views_count"] as! Int
            self.bucketsCount = data["buckets_count"] as! Int
            self.attachmentsCount = data["attachments_count"] as! Int
            self.reboundCount = data["rebounds_count"] as! Int

            self.commentsUrl = Utils.getStringFromJSON(data, key: "comments_url")
            self.bucketsUrl = Utils.getStringFromJSON(data, key: "buckets_url")
            self.likesUrl = Utils.getStringFromJSON(data, key: "likes_url")
            self.title = Utils.getStringFromJSON(data, key: "title")
            self.attachmentUrl = Utils.getStringFromJSON(data, key: "attachments_url")
            self.reboundUrl = Utils.getStringFromJSON(data, key: "rebounds_url")

            let dateInfo = Utils.getStringFromJSON(data, key: "created_at")
            self.date = Utils.formatDate(dateInfo)

            let desc = Utils.getStringFromJSON(data, key: "description")
            self.description = Utils.stripHTML(desc)

            let images = data["images"] as! NSDictionary
            self.imageUrl = Utils.getStringFromJSON(images, key: "normal")

            //let tags = data["tags"] as! NSArray

          if let userData = data["user"] as? NSDictionary {
            self.user = User(data: userData)
        }
      }
    }
```

and Code for DribbbleBase

```
import Foundation

class DribbbleBase {
    var id: Int

    init(data: NSDictionary){
        self.id = data["id"] as! Int
    }
}
```

Please help me.. And Please Bear in mind i am fairly new to Swift

Thanks in Advance
Aryan

Comment: You've declared `shot` as a non-optional object, but it looks to me that it's somehow `nil` (perhaps something is failing in `self.loadShots()`??)

Comment: But the problem is that the Shot Class returns an NSDictionary

Answer (score 0):

you declared shot property in your PopularShotsCollectionViewController and you didn't initialize it so shot is be nil. Then you tried to access commentsUrl property of shot which is nil in the loadComments method. You should instantiate shot in the init or view did load method of your view controller

Comment: HI Ahmed Can you please give me an example of how this can be done in code and i have edit the question and added code for the Shot Class and the problem is that the Shot Class returns an NSDictionary..

Comment: I can't find the code that define Shot class in your question

Comment: Please Refresh it then you will find it

Comment: From your code, you must instantiate Shot with a dictionary, you also have to assign a value to commentsUrl property of Shot after it's initialization else, you will end up with the same error.